# Angular JS URL rewriting issues

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting

I am currently working on an Angular app and facing some issues with URLs.

**Problem**:

My application has the main page which has multiple sections and all sections fetch data from backend. There is an animated scroller on each section, e.g. If I am at section1 and select Section3, it scrolls me to Section3 in a nice animated way. I have few pages which also are fetched from backend but totally changes the view. This is the hierarchy of views:

**Page1**:

Section1, Section2, Section3, Section4, Section5 (Will be visible in whole application aka HEADER)

**Section5**:

Link1, Link2 (Each link is totally a separate view)

If I am on Link1 and click any of the Section, it appends # to the URL relatively and doesn't redirect me to the actual section.

**Question(s)**:

1. I do not want to use # anywhere at all, how can I get rid of it?
2. I do not want to remove animation from my home page.
3. If I am on some other view and click on any section (HEADER), it should take me to that particular position, how can I achieve this?

This is my routes.js file:

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);

    webApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        }

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })
            //section2
                .when('/section2', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/section3', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/section4', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/section5', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/section7', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/section8', {
                templateUrl : 'application/header.jsp',
                controller  : 'homeController'
            })

            .when('/Link1', {
                templateUrl : 'application/link1.jsp',
                controller  : 'link1Controller'
            })

            .when('/Link2', {
                templateUrl : 'application/link2.jsp',
                controller  : 'link2Controller'
            })

            .when('/Link3', {
                templateUrl : 'application/link3.jsp',
                controller  : 'link3Controller'
            });
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated or if anything is missing or required, please do let me know.

Comment: If you don't want to use # so why are you relying on ngRoute?

Comment: @ChrisHermut Because of deep linking of URLs? I don't mind removing it if this helps solving my problem(s)